# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '095-10197-10' to data type int. Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

If I use simple `select * FROM View`, I am getting the proper output but when i try to filtered out the rows using where condition with specific columns (e.g: `SELECT * FROM VIEW where Amount = '1.85'`, then I am getting an error like

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '095-10197-10' to
>   data type int.

IF I check '095-10197-10' VALUE , there is not such value in any column coming through View.

Any idea what causing the issue.

Comment: you'll get more answers if you put all the relevant tags in ..

Comment: um ...lose the single quotes around 1.85

Comment: What is the exact where clause giving you trouble.  If it is your example what is the datatype of Amount?

Comment: @fnostro: I removed the single quotes still same issue.

Comment: @JoeC : datatype of Amount is decimal. Amount is one of the column if i use in filter gives me an error. Another non working e.g is select * FROM view where AccountNumber = 'Unrealized Gain-Loss' where Accountnumber is of varchar(50) ... working example is Select * FROM View where Id = 13456

Comment: unless you can provide more code and table structures it's a guessing game. But i would start by comparing execution plans and look for explicit and implicit conversions

Comment: You obviously have a column in your view that is a varchar datatype where it is expected to have a numeric value but one of the rows contains that value.

Comment: If you must make string comparisons make sure there are no extraneous spaces, use trim functions on the field.  Also, if `SELECT * From View` works and `SELECT * From View where Amount = 1.85` does not, then the error is not where you think it is.  Analyze the View code and the source tables.

Comment: I am trying to narrow down the data so that i have some subset to see which rows are giving an error. I tried many cast/convert statement but none works.

Comment: With ad-hoc SQL you will notice, that commands are not processed in the order you might expect it. Where is this `095-10197-10` coming from? Might be, that there is some attempt to do subtraction maths?

Comment: Yes, unless you can post all the code needed to reproduce the behavior, the best anyone here can do is guess.